# This spec creates very few connects, is that plausible?

Tags: alloy

I'm attempting exercise A.2.1 from the book http://alloytools.org/book.html. Having got this far, I find that when stepping through instances I only ever get 2 *connects* links, no matter how many *requests* links, when using the *MiniSat* solver. When using *MiniSat plus Unsat core*, I sometimes get more *connects*, but not many *requests*. Obviously, these all satisfy the model, but it feels wrong to me. Am I over-thinking this?

```
module exercises/telephone

sig Phone {
    , requests : set Phone
    , connects: lone Phone
} 

fact minimum_system {
    some requests
    some connects
}

fact dont_call_yourself {
  no p: Phone | p.connects = p
  no p: Phone | p in p.requests
}

fact connect_from_a_request {
    no (connects - requests)
}

fact only_receive_once {
    all p: Phone.connects | one ~connects[p]
}

fact receiver_or_caller_only {
    no (Phone.connects & Phone.~connects)
}

pred show {}

run show for exactly 12 Phone
```

Comment: If you're not sure whether the code actually works the way it should, it's not yet ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please give it some leeway?

Comment: Dear @Mast, I'm not sure you understand how Alloy works. It generates a range of solutions and "works" is sometimes a matter of judgement. I tried posting stuff to SO and got bounced off there too.

Comment: Does or doesn't the result comply to your expectations?

Comment: Really, if you want to judge this entry, please take a look at Alloy. It's closer to data science in that this is not that simple a question to answer. I'm beginning to wonder if this the right place for us.

Comment: If you can't answer that question, I'm beginning to wonder that too. You talk about 'us', are you part of a group that we can reach about this?

Comment: Would you perhaps be more interested in our [Datascience site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @Mast Looking at the help section you pointed, I think this is valid use. As Steve said, the model is correct. It would be nice if you could allow this tag to grow. If it doesn't I am sure you got enough credit to delete it. So unless you can point out an exact rule we violate I suggest we continue like we started.

Comment: @PeterKriens https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650 We're more than happy for this tag to grow. Just like every other language and question just follow our rules. If you don't like them post on Meta.

Comment: @Peilonrayz That rule is not applicable here.

Comment: If that is the case then the OP should be [edit]ed to be worded in such a way that doesn't make it sound like it's asking what's wrong with code that doesn't behave as intended - the users "policing" this site don't know the intricacies of every programming language that ever existed. But they are very effective at voting to "close" / *put on hold* (to prevent the inevitable mess caused by answers to off-topic questions that later get edited into shape) questions where the OP is asking reviewers to find what's wrong with their code that's not working: knowledge of the tech is irrelevant.

Comment: Note that a "closed" question on this network isn't the end of the post at all - it just means the post should be edited before it can accept answers on the site. The first edit made to a "closed" question brings it to the *reopen* review queue, where reviewers cast *reopen* votes. The goal is to make sure all posts on the site are on-topic, not to slam down new language tags.

Comment: Lastly, having a discussion about the intricacies of the tag on [meta] can't hurt; it would give other users visibility on what's special about this language and why we should avoid casting close votes on these posts. For example posting an Excel question in the [tag:vba] tag and mentioning that "Excel freezes and stops responding" would often attract downvotes and close votes by users unfamiliar with the tech - a post on meta and a tag wiki edit helped clarify that such behavior is normal because X, it's a perfectly reviewable performance/algorithm issue that doesn't mean the code is broken.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon perhaps you already saw this but for posterity: [the alloy tag is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10533/120114).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get lots of instances, it's not really practical to look through them all. What most Alloy users would do in this case is to add a constraint to the show predicate to see if you can get the instance you expect. So I modified it to

```
pred show {
#connects > 4
#requests > 4
}
```

and now I see instances with more than 4 connects and requests.

Another suggestion: don't use exactly unless you really need to. You usually want to look for all instances up to some bound, and if you set it to exactly, you might find that you get no instances because it's not possible to construct one with exactly that number. For example, if you don't allow conference calls and you require phones to matched one to one, and you then set the bound to "exactly 3" you would get no solutions.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. You should be able to see that Mast posted a comment that the question is off-topic. It takes a little bit of time to get things close around here.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Please point out the rule that is violated.

Comment: @PeterKriens the OP is worded in such a way that people that aren't familiar with the tech read it as the description of a script that is not behaving the way it was intended. The first criteria for a question to be on-topic on this site, is that the code works as intended. We *review working code* to make it better in every way, but we don't do bug-hunting. I cannot judge whether the OP's code works correctly or not and it seems rather blurry so I'll err on the "let it slide" side of the fence, but people vote with what they see, and right now the OP reads like it's asking about broken code.